# Full screen button in android studio

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to make a button on Android studio which fully covers the main activity? The functionality of the app requires a button which takes full screen input, and wrapping it to parent is not fully covering the screen.

Comment: Could you make your post clearer?  How is this relevant to C++?

Comment: Do you want single button in a screen? Then use `match_parent` . To get full screen,  `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code before `setContentView(R.layout.splash);`

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and make the button

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched and found Nothing about Covering the Whole screen.
Instead of Covering Screen You can try the Following Approach that I know:
i.e

> You can Hide Status bar and Buttons to hide status bar Below is Code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();

setContentView(R.layout.splash); // be sure you call this AFTER requestFeature
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating full screen is pretty easy using android button in android studio

Steps to create full screen button in android studio

1. Create a Button
2. Set layout width and height to match_parent
3. Set Button alpha to 0 (zero)
4. Set button constraints to parent

XML code of a full screen button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFullScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="buttonPressed"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```